# Is there a way to "beat" the opening circus area?

Tags: silent-hill-3

When you first start off Silent Hill 3 you begin in a circus. However, as I quickly discovered after accidentally running into a pit and dying, it's just a dream sequence which you wake up from after dying.

Is there any "end" to this circus world which forces me to wake up, or do I just wander around aimlessly until I die?

Comment: You didn't go on the rollercoaster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sequence has a scripted ending - no matter what you do, as you advance through the area, you will always die when you get to the rollercoaster.  The only way to stay here forever would be to just stand around or run in circles.

> This is actually important later, when you visit the Silent Hill Amusement Park in the flesh, and have to be careful not to die the same way you saw in your dream!